# IIS URL Rewrite Module - Regular Expression for URL

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewrite-module

I would like to redirect the below old URL:

```
https://domain1.xyz.com/content/images/1ca9551bc00357f63c608b5d90ca7c4652187487.png
```

to the new URL:

```
https://domain2.xyz.com/originalfiles/1ca9551bc00357f63c608b5d90ca7c4652187487.png
```

My web.config file has below configuration but I cannot get it to work:

```
<rewrite>
       <rules>
          <rule name="Rewrite Images to CDN" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain2.xyz.com/originalfiles/{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                <conditions>
                   <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain1.xyz.com" />
                   <add input="{URL}" pattern="content/images/(/*.*)" />
                </conditions>
         </rule>
       </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Above configuration redirects to this URL which is incorrect:

```
https://domain2.xyz.com/originalfiles/content/images/1ca9551bc00357f63c608b5d90ca7c4652187487.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following rule:

```
<rewrite>
       <rules>
          <rule name="Rewrite Images to CDN" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="content/images(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                   <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain1.xyz.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain2.xyz.com/originalfiles{R:1}" />
           </rule>
        </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me. Also I realized that every time I made a change in the web.config file, IIS or browser seem to have a Cached response and the redirect did not work. I tried opening up the old Image URL in an incognito browser window and it worked for me.